# i don't know how to display the cursor data oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor, plsqldeveloper

I don't know how to display the cursor data I create a cursor that returns multiple rows and I want to view the row and I don't know how

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE  CURSOR CurEscal IS
SELECT 
    ESCALE.NUMVOL, ( to_number ( to_char ( ESCALE.DATEED, 'MI' ) ) - to_number ( to_char ( ESCALE.DATEEA, 'MI' ) ) ) AS "duree par min", AEROPORT.NOMAER
FROM
    ESCALE
    JOIN AEROPORT ON ESCALE.REFAER = AEROPORT.REFAER 
WHERE
    NUMVOL IN ( SELECT ESCALE.NUMVOL FROM ESCALE GROUP BY ESCALE.NUMVOL HAVING Count( ESCALE.NUMESC ) >= 1 );
BEGIN
    --Open the CurEscal CURSOR
    IF NOT (CurEscal%ISOPEN) THEN
        OPEN CurEscal;
    END IF;

    --FETCH
    FOR i IN CurEscal LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('I don't know how I need your help');
    END LOOP;

    --Close the CurEscal CURSOR
    IF CurEscal%ISOPEN THEN
        CLOSE CurEscal;
    END IF;    
END;
/
```

can someone help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be

```
dbms_output.put_line(i.numvol ||', '|| i."duree par min" ||', '|| i.NOMAER);
```

Though, if you use a cursor `FOR` loop, everything is somewhat simpler as you don't have to declare/open/fetch/close the cursor, e.g.

```
BEGIN
   FOR i
      IN (SELECT escale.numvol,
                 (  TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (escale.dateed, 'MI'))
                  - TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (escale.dateea, 'MI')))
                    AS duree_par_min,
                 aeroport.nomaer
            FROM escale JOIN aeroport ON escale.refaer = aeroport.refaer
           WHERE numvol IN (  SELECT escale.numvol
                                FROM escale
                            GROUP BY escale.numvol
                              HAVING COUNT (escale.numesc) >= 1))
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
         i.numvol || ', ' || i.duree_par_min || ', ' || i.nomaer);
   END LOOP;
END;
```